# rundeck - ConfigurationFailure: SSH Keyfile does not exist

Tags: linux, ssh, rundeck

When I try a command in Rundeck, it shows:

```
Failed: ConfigurationFailure: SSH Keyfile does not exist: ~/.ssh/id_rsa
Execution failed: 19: [Workflow step failures: {1=Dispatch failed on 1 nodes: [my.server.com: ConfigurationFailure: SSH Keyfile does not exist: ~/.ssh/id_rsa]}, Node failures: {my.server.com=[ConfigurationFailure: SSH Keyfile does not exist: ~/.ssh/id_rsa]}]
```

I have generated ssh-key and I can use it to connect SSH without password.

In rundeck machine, the key was generated in `~/.ssh/id_rsa`

In remote machine, the key was copied to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check the project settings, what is the "Default SSH key" listed?

- [Rundeck admin documentation](http://rundeck.org/docs/administration/project-setup.html)

If the value is "var/lib/rundeck/.ssh/id_rsa" then that indicates you have installed rundeck using either a Debian or RPM package. In this case Rundeck executes as a different user, explaining why the key in your home directory doesn't get used.